# Django 4.0 Dynamically adding a new form

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-forms

I am trying to add a form to a new row in there own columns with a button then having all the forms saved with the submit button. Only the first form is being saved, I am assuming it is the javascript doing it but I have no clue with javascript and ChatGPT is not helping lol

```
{% extends 'containers/base.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <h3 class="m-4">All Containers</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            {% if success %}
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                Container/s have been added successfully.
                <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="alert-link">Go to Home Page.</a>
            </div>
            {% else %}
            <div class="card bg-light mb-3">
                <div class="card-header">Add Containers</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Container Number</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Driver In</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Date In</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Driver Out</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Date Out</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Container Size</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Empty/full</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Import/Export</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <form action="{% url 'add' %}" method="POST">
                                    {% for form in formset %}
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    {{ formset.management_form }}
                                    <tbody class="container-table-body" id="container-table-body">
                                        <tr>  
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                                    {{ form.company_name }}
                                                </div>                                 
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                                    {{ form.container_number }}
                                                </div>                                           
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                                    {{ form.driver_in_name }}
                                                </div>                                        
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                                    {{ form.driver_in_date }}
                                                </div>                                           
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                                    {{ form.driver_out_name }}
                                                </div>                                         
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                                    {{ form.driver_out_date }}
                                                </div>                                          
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                                    {{ form.container_size }}
                                                </div>                                       
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                                    {{ form.container_empty_full }}
                                                </div>                                       
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                                    {{ form.container_import_export }}
                                                </div>                                       
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                                    
                                </form>
                                <button id="addForm" class="btn btn-primary">Add Container</button>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("addForm").addEventListener("click", function() {
            var tableBody = document.getElementById("container-table-body");
            var lastRow = tableBody.lastElementChild.cloneNode(true);
            tableBody.appendChild(lastRow);
        });
    </script>
    
{% endblock %}
```

I am positive that my add in my views.py is working but I will include is just in case I am missing something

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.forms import formset_factory

from .models import Container
from .forms import ContainerAdd

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'containers/index.html',{
        'containers': Container.objects.all()
    })

def add(request):
    ContainerFormSet = formset_factory(ContainerAdd, extra=1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ContainerFormSet(request.POST, prefix='container')
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                if form.is_valid():
                    new_company_name = form.cleaned_data['company_name']
                    new_container_number = form.cleaned_data['container_number']
                    new_driver_in_name = form.cleaned_data['driver_in_name']
                    new_driver_in_date = form.cleaned_data['driver_in_date']
                    new_driver_out_name = form.cleaned_data['driver_out_name']
                    new_driver_out_date = form.cleaned_data['driver_out_date']
                    new_container_size = form.cleaned_data['container_size']
                    new_container_empty_full = form.cleaned_data['container_empty_full']
                    new_container_import_export = form.cleaned_data['container_import_export']

                    new_container = Container(
                        company_name=new_company_name,
                        container_number=new_container_number,
                        driver_in_name=new_driver_in_name,
                        driver_in_date=new_driver_in_date,
                        driver_out_name=new_driver_out_name,
                        driver_out_date=new_driver_out_date,
                        container_size=new_container_size,
                        container_empty_full=new_container_empty_full,
                        container_import_export=new_container_import_export
                    )
                    new_container.save()

            return render(request, 'containers/add.html', {
                'formset': ContainerFormSet(),
                'success': True
            })
    else:
        formset = ContainerFormSet(prefix='container')

    return render(request, 'containers/add.html', {
        'formset': formset
    })
```

I have tried multiple different scripts that have been given to me by Chatgpt but no help and struggling to find anything online

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def add(request):
    ContainerFormSet = formset_factory(ContainerAdd, extra=1)
    formset = ContainerFormSet()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ContainerFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                if form.cleaned_data:
                    container = form.save(commit=False)
                    container.save()
                return redirect('to_some_page')
    return render(request, 'containers/add.html', {'formset': formset})
```

Comment: Gave that a go but no longer saves anything